# MPI send struct with bytes array and integers

Tags: c++, opencv, struct, mpi, mat

I would like to send image data(array of unsigned char), width and height from rank 0 to rank 1. What is the best way to do this? I've read that to send complex data structure in MPI we can use packaging data or create own data type. What is better in my case?

I tried to do that by creating a new data type. But I get fault: `Segmentation fault (signal 11)`. When I remove array from my struct it's works. So what is wrong in sending this array?

My struct:

```
typedef struct MyImage {
    int w;
    int h;
    unsigned char *data;
} image;
```

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {

    int size, rank;
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int blocksCount = 3;
    int blocksLength[3] = {1, 1, 512 * 512 * 3};

    //   I also tried MPI_BYTE
    MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR};
    MPI_Aint offsets[3];
    MPI_Datatype custom_type;
    offsets[0] = offsetof(image, w);
    offsets[1] = offsetof(image, h);
    offsets[3] = offsetof(image, data);

    MPI_Type_create_struct(blocksCount, blocksLength, offsets, types, &custom_type);
    MPI_Type_commit(&custom_type);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    if (rank == 0) {

    Mat mat = imread("/home/user/image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
        image send;
        send.w = mat.size().width;
        send.h = mat.size().height;
        send.data = mat.data;
        MPI_Send(&send, 1, custom_type, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    }
    if (rank == 1) {
        image recv;
        MPI_Status status;
        MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, custom_type, 0, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    MPI_Type_free(&custom_type);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there one more `MPI_INT` than it should be, here `MPI_Datatype types[3] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_INT, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR};`?

Comment: @gurka, thx I edited this. But it's no problem. Simply my mistake when creating this example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The sender segfaults because you are trying to send the data starting from the location of the `Mat.data` pointer itself and not from the location in memory where it points to. The receiver segfaults because there is no space to store the 768 KiB of data (should any arrive).

You could pack the data first, but that would require an additional buffer. Your best option is to simply send two messages:

- one with the image size, so that the receiver could prepare an appropriately sized `Mat` object;
- one with the image data itself.

Sometimes it is simply better to send two messages instead of packing everything into just one.

```
typedef struct MyImage {
   int w;
   int h;
} image;

int blocksCount = 2;
int blocksLength[2] = {1, 1};

MPI_Datatype types[2] = {MPI_INT, MPI_INT};
MPI_Aint offsets[2];
MPI_Datatype custom_type;
offsets[0] = offsetof(image, w);
offsets[1] = offsetof(image, h);

MPI_Type_create_struct(blocksCount, blocksLength, offsets, types, &custom_type);
MPI_Type_commit(&custom_type);

if (rank == 0) {
    Mat mat = imread("/home/user/image.jpg", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
    image send;
    send.w = mat.size().width;
    send.h = mat.size().height;
    // Send image dimensions
    MPI_Send(&send, 1, custom_type, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // Send image data
    MPI_Send(mat.data, send.w*send.h*3, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 1, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
}
if (rank == 1) {
    image recv;
    MPI_Status status;
    // Receive image dimensions
    MPI_Recv(&recv, 1, custom_type, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    // Allocate image matrix
    Mat mat(Size(recv.w, recv.h), CV_8UC3);
    // Receive image data
    MPI_Recv(mat.data, recv.w*recv.h*3, MPI_UNSIGNED_CHAR, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much it's what I wanted.

Comment: Isn't it expensive to MPI_Send just 1 custom_type?

Comment: @KcFnMi, it depends. In that particular case, the send will take a fraction of the time it takes to transfer the image, so it won't be that expensive.